# Lodash map to array of objects

Tags: lodash, transformation

I'm starting from a jQuery wrapper with a number of `<A>`-tag elements in it. The result I want is:

```
[{href: "http://...", text: "The inner text"}, {...}, ...]
```

Thus far I got this:

```
_.map($pubs, ($pub) => _.pick($pub, 'href', 'innerText'))
```

That works, but it looks like there's a better way, and the inner text property is named "innerText" instead of "text". And I do want the `innerText` of the elements and not just the `.text()` as that doesn't clean up the output (newlines, whitespace,...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), and [assign `text` to a new variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names). Now you can create a new object with the `href`, and `text` variables using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const links = $('a').toArray();

const result = links.map(({ href, innerText: text }) => ({ href, text }));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a>
```

You can also use jQuery's ['.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```js
const result = $('a').map((k, { href, innerText: text }) => ({ href, text })).toArray();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a>
```

Comment: I'm using Babel compiled ES6, and I guess there's a bug there as it compiles the `map` statement to: `return pubs.map(function (_ref) { var href = _ref.href, text = _ref.innerText; return { href: href, text: text }; });` but `_ref` is the index argument in the `map` method, not the value. Any idea on how to resolve that?

Comment: The 1st param is the value in Array#map. Did you use `.toArray()` on the jQuery object?

Comment: Right! I'm using a framework that uses a lot of chaining and apparently reconverts an array of elements to a jQuery wrapper in each step, so my `toArray` call had no effect.

Comment: The little annoying things in life :) I've also added a solution that uses jQuery's .map(). It still requires `.toArray()`, but only at the end.